# Custom PHP extension on Azure DevOps Microsoft-hosted Windows agent

Tags: php, windows, azure, devops

I have an existing Azure DevOps pipeline that builds a PHP application and deploys it to a Windows App Service. This application now needs a custom PHP extension that must be present during the 'composer install' step run on the build agent.

Is it possible to install a PHP extension on a Microsoft-hosted Windows agent? If yes, how?